# ASP.NET MVC Routing problem with BeginForm() inside the foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, razor, url-routing

To start with, please forgive me if the problem is trivial, but I am a complete novice when it comes to ASP.NET. I just need to pass my project and I am completely stuck at one point.

I am preparing a shopping basket functionality for the online shop. The available articles are listed in the following way:

```
@foreach( var element in Model.all_products )
{
  using( Html.BeginForm( "AddToBasket", "Basket", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor( Model=>element.id ), amountInBasket = Html.DisplayFor( Model => element.amountInBasket ) }, FormMethod.Get ) )
  {
     <tbody>
        <tr id="@Html.DisplayFor( Model => element.id )" class="warning">
           <th scope="row">   @Html.DisplayFor( Model => element.name )</th>
           <td>               @Html.DisplayFor( Model => element.price )</td>
           <td>               @Html.DisplayFor( Model => element.measureUnit )</td>
           <td>               @Html.TextBoxFor( Model => element.amountInBasket )</td>
           <td> <input type="submit" class="btn-success btn" value="Add to basket"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  } }
```

In a foreach loop I create a form for each article available in the shop. Each form contains a submit which is to add the given amount of the given product (`element.amountInBasket`) to the shopping basket.
My idea is to recognize which submit has been clicked by the `element.id` (article id in the database) and to pass it together with `element.amountInBasket` to my AddToBasket method in BasketController.
The AddToBasket declaration starts as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> AddToBasket( decimal amountInBasket, int id )
    { ...
```

Now my problem is that the url generated by the BeginForm() for, let's say id=2 and amountInBasket=3, is:

> https://localhost:44356/Basket/AddToBasket/2?element.amountInBasket=2

which leads to the error (it states that the second param is null).
After some tries I've found out, that the url expected by the AddToBasket method is:

> https://localhost:44356/Basket/AddToBasket/2?amountInBasket=3

so the problem is with the "element." part of my url. Once I manually remove this, I reach my method and everything works perfect.

Could somebody please tell me how to fix this issue? For me it doesn't really matter if the "element." part is removed from the url or it stays there and only the method is modified to accept it - I just need to reach my method.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
using( Html.BeginForm( "AddToBasket", "Basket", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor( Model=>element.id ), amountInBasket = Html.DisplayFor( Model => element.amountInBasket ) }, FormMethod.Get ) )
```

to this:

```
using( Html.BeginForm( "AddToBasket", "Basket", new { id = element.id , amountInBasket = element.amountInBasket }, FormMethod.Get ) )
```